# How can I customise different views to the normal users and admin using django?

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-login

I tried out the below view function. But the normal user's page `studenthpage` is never getting rendered, while the `superuser` is able to login. Instead of `elif user.is_active` I even tried just `else` condition, still not successful. Can anyone help?

```
def login(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
         username = request.POST.get('username')
         password =request.POST.get('password')
         user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
         if user is not None :
              auth_login(request,user)

              if user.is_superuser:               
                   return redirect('adminhpage')
              elif user.is_active:
                   return redirect('studenthpage')             
         else:
              messages.info(request, 'Username OR password is incorrect')
    
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'login.html', context)
```

Comment: Exactly what happens with a normal user?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are probably logging in as a `user` that has a `superuser` status, hence why it always logs in as an admin. Ensure that the `user` you're logging in with doesn't have a `superuser` status and see if that works.